# Why don't my :active' or :checked selectors work?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, sidebar

I have a hidden sidebar menu on my website, if I open my website on my desktop, my hidden sidebar has 100px width (not full), so to reveal it all you must do is hover over it. If I open my website on a mobile device, my hidden sidebar has no width, and I must click the button to reveal the sidebar.

**HTML**:

```
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav sidenav-wrapper">
  <img class="logo1" src="../img/logo1.png"><br><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id="contoh" class="content-section-b">
  <div class="mobiletoggle">
    <label class="fa fa-bars" for="showblock"></label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="showblock" />
  </div>
</div>
```

In the code above I use `checkbox` to change 'click', because I just want to use CSS.

**CSS**:

```
.sidenav {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #111;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  padding-top: 60px;
  transition: 0.8s; 
}
.logo1 {
  height: 10%;
  width: auto;
  padding-left: 20px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
.sidenav:hover {
   width: 250px;
   transition: 0.8s;
}
.sidenav:hover ~ #contoh { 
   background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4);
   filter: grayscale(100%);
}
.sidenav:hover .logo1 {  
   height: auto;
   width: 95%;
   padding-left: 10px;
   transition: 0.8s;
}
.sidenav a {
  float:left;
  width:100%;
  padding: 8px 8px 8px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 20px;
  color: #818181;
  display: block;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 1300ms
}
.sidenav a:hover, .offcanvas a:focus {
  color: #f1f1f1;
  background-color:#5fa2db;
  font-size: 30px;
}
#showblock {
  display: none;
}
@media screen and (min-width:768px) {
  .mobiletoggle {
    display:none;
  }
}
@media screen and (max-width:767px) {
  .sidenav { 
    width:0px; 
  }
  #showblock:checked + .sidenav {
    width: 250px;
    transition: 0.8s;
  }
}
```

In the code above I used `:checked`, it's just a little bit different if I use `:active`. The problem is why my `:checked`/`:active` did not work? I looked into this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nMNJE/), and it works fine, so why can't I use it? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your CSS, modify your HTML to:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="showblock">
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav sidenav-wrapper">
  <img class="logo1" src="../img/logo1.png"><br><br>
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>
<div id ="contoh" class="content-section-b">
  <div class="mobiletoggle">
    <label class="fa fa-bars" for="showblock"></label>
  </div>
</div>
```

The `input` `#showblock` should be above the `div` `#mySidenav` in order for your CSS to work.

```
#showblock:checked + .sidenav {
  width: 250px;
  transition: 0.8s;
}
```

Comment: oh my God, thanks for your answer, this is my fault. :D, and can you help me in this question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130500/how-to-trigger-css-transition-before-hover/42133321#42133321 so many thanks